# Why use "0 auto" in margin, not "auto" only?

Tags: html, css

I know that `margin: 0 auto` will center element with specified width, because 0 mean 0 margin for top and bottom, and auto mean share the same margin for right and left.

But [this article](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#:%7E:text=floating%20replaced%20elements-,If%20%27margin-top%27%2C%20or%20%27margin-bottom%27%20are%20%27auto%27%2C%20their%20used%20value%20is%200.,-If%20%27height%27%20and) says that

> If 'margin-top', or 'margin-bottom' are 'auto', their used value is 0.

So, why don't use `margin: auto` only? Because the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` will be 0 when their value are auto.

Comment: Because `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` will not be always zero when `auto` is set.

Comment: @Raptor So, is the article wrong?

Comment: the **used** value is 0. But CSS can be overwritten by other selectors, classes, etc.

Comment: @Raptor Oh, I got it, thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Raptor your logic doesn't stand here because if another Selector will override margin it will do it the same way for auto or 0. You can use `margin:auto` if you want. You will only have a different output in case you are using Flexbox or CSS grid because in that case auto will not compute to 0 otherwise both are the same

Comment: @TemaniAfif you're right.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Got it